# Search For Existance of File, If File Exists, Replace File With NewFile,

Tags: batch-file, replace, cmd, dos

I've been trying to write this BATCH-SCRIPT, however I'm VERY NEW to scripting --all I've ever studied was MEL (Maya Embedded Language). All I want to do is:

1 SEARCH C:/ for a file (originalFile)

2 IF the file EXIST, I want to perform a series of commands, but more than anything I'm trying to REPLACE the originalFile with another file (decoyFile)

3 Then I would like to RENAME the decoyFile to the name of the originalFile (for if it were the same name as the originalFile to start with, it would be getting REPLACED as well --or there would be some confusion)

*** The TRICK is that I would like to search for some text within the decoyFile that will let me know that it IS the decoyFile... maybe "decoyText" ***

I figure that after I LOCATE the originalFile (Step 1), I would have to CHECK (or Findstr) to see if it contains the decoyText... IF decoyText EXIST then EXIT or do nothing, but IF decoyText does not EXIST then REPLACE originalFile with decoyFile

This is the 1st time I've thought of a good enough reason to write a script using MS-DOS, all I could manage was this 1st line with it echoing that the file DOES EXIST... Everything I try after that just doesn't seem to want to work.

Your help would be greatly appreciated... Thank You...

@echo off
cls
if exist dir /s originalFile.txt (

)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /d /r C:\ %%a in (*) do if exist "%%~fa\originalFile" set "originalFile=%%~fa\originalFile"
if not defined originalFile echo originalFile not found&goto:eof
find "decoyText" "%originalFile%" && echo %originalFile% is not original&goto:eof
for /d /r C:\ %%a in (*) do if exist "%%~fa\decoyFile" set "decoyFile=%%~fa\decoyFile"
if not defined decoyFile echo decoyFile not found&goto:eof
find "decoyText" "%decoyFile%" || echo %decoyFile% is no decoy&goto:eof
move "%decoyFile%" "%originalFile%" || Error! Can not remove %originalFile%!
```